# Why does clang 3.4 implement `std::function` in such a weird way?

Tags: c++, function, c++11, functor

The following code is excerpted from the latest `libc++` header `<functional>` of clang 3.4:

At line 1636:

```
typedef __allocator_destructor<_Ap> _Dp;
unique_ptr<__base, _Dp> __hold(__a.allocate(1), _Dp(__a, 1));
::new (__hold.get()) _FF(_VSTD::move(__f), _Alloc(__a));
__f_ = __hold.release();
```

Why use `unique_ptr` to manage dynamically allocated storage here? Please note `__hold` will never call its `deleter` because it finally releases the control of its internal storage!

Why not just write as follows:

```
__f_ = __a.allocate(1);
::new (__f_) _FF(_VSTD::move(__f), _Alloc(__a));
```

Comment: nothing says that this is dynamic allocated memory. this is  a placement new on a space returned by an allocator. this allocator could use stack space for all we know.

Comment: @v.oddou, In concept, all storage allocated by the allocator can be seen as `dynamically allocated storage`

Comment: exception safety reason?

Comment: @Bryan is right, what happens if the constructor throws?

Comment: What's weird exactly? Unique ptr is the default. One should always use it to manage memory, unless it's shared.

Comment: Are the implementations of the STL be ever readable?

Comment: @alfC Not with all those exceptions and templates... I think it really helps readability to avoid the first and use the second sparingly... Pity, STL implementators cannot avoid either...

Comment: @cmaster: comments and well named variables (unlike `__f_, _Ap, _Dp, _VSTD, _FF, __a`) would go a long ways though

Comment: It is sad at many levels, 1) STL *implementation* is hard to understand (and it is a pity because one can learn a lot from STL) 2) It gives the impression that to write a robust library one needs *ultimately* to write code like this (and that impression may be true, even sadder). C++ should evolve, if nothing else, to make STL easier to implement.

Answer (score 2):

```
__f_ = __a.allocate(1);
```

Alright, you've allocated memory and stored the pointer.

```
::new (__f_) _FF(_VSTD::move(__f), _Alloc(__a));
```

This throws an exception, and the stack unwinds.  Oops, you just leaked your dynamic memory!  The obvious way to prevent memory leaks is.... `std::unique_ptr`.